# Can 2 lines with the different coefficients be the same?

Tags: linear-algebra

> If  $ax + by = cx + dy$ then does $a=c$ and $b=d$?

I would think so by the mathcing coefficients method?

Comment: If the intention is "for any $x$ and $y$", then yes. Otherwise no; for instance, if $x=2$ and $y=-2$ then $x+y=2x+2y$ but $1\neq 2$.

Comment: If $x$ and $y$ have specific values then only in special cases do they have to be the same, such as when $x$ and $y$ are linearly independent vectors.

Comment: You mention lines in the title. Are you starting with the equations of two lines, $ax+by=k$ and $cx+dy=k$, and then equating them? If so, then when $k=0$ the coefficients need not be the same for the two equations to represent the same line.

Answer (score 1):

Substitute $(x,y)=(1,0)$ to get an equation involving $a,b,c,d$, and then do the same with $(x,y)=(0,1)$.

Comment: Complement for dbz1: this is because the equation holds for all $x$ and $y$ in $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes if $\frac{a}{c}=\frac{b}{d}$.

(Ignoring cases with zeroes, but that should be clear enough anyway)